# Can you extract SHA1 from a .jks file?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, code-signing

I have `debug.keystore` files (same as `.jks` files) in several React Native projects, and have the SHA1 value of a keystore files I used sometime in the past. I want to know which of the `debug.keystore` files it matches. Is there a way to extract the SHA1 value from a `.keystore` or `.jks` file? I know you can use `./gradlew signingReport` in the `android` folder of the project, but this doesn't work if the project doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore KEYSTORE_PATH -alias KEY -storepass STOREPASS -keypass KEYPASS
```

When you don't specify a key for the debug build, Android Studio uses the same debug key for all projects.